# How do I list the department name from another table in my results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

The following is my EMPLOYEES table:

```
create table EMPLOYEES
    (EmpID    char(4)         unique Not null,
     Ename    varchar(10),
     Job      varchar(9),
     MGR      char(4),
     Hiredate date,
     Salary   decimal(7,2),
     Comm     decimal(7,2),
     DeptNo   char(2)         not null,
         Primary key(EmpID),
         Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));


insert into EMPLOYEES values (7839,'King','President',null,'17-Nov-11',5000,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7698,'Blake','Manager',7839,'01-May-11',2850,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7782,'Clark','Manager',7839,'02-Jun-11',2450,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7566,'Jones','Manager',7839,'02-Apr-11',2975,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7499,'Allen','Salesman',7698,'20-Feb-11',1600,300,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7844,'Turner','Salesman',7698,'08-Sep-11',1500,0,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7900,'James','Clerk',7698,'22-Feb-12',950,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7521,'Ward','Salesman',7698,'22-Feb-12',1250,500,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7902,'Ford','Analyst',7566,'03-Dec-11',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7369,'Smith','Clerk',7902,'17-Dec-10',800,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7788,'Scott','Analyst',7566,'09-Dec-12',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7876,'Adams','Clerk',7788,'12-Jan-10',1100,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7934,'Miller','Clerk',7782,'23-Jan-12',1300,null,10);
```

The following is my DEPARTMENTS table:

```
create table DEPARTMENTS
(DeptNo   char(2)  unique Not null,
DName    varchar(14),
Location varchar(13),
Primary key(DeptNo));

insert into DEPARTMENTS values (10,'Accounting','New York');
insert into DEPARTMENTS values (20,'Research','Dallas');
insert into DEPARTMENTS Values (30,'Sales','Chicago');
insert into DEPARTMENTS values (40,'Operations','Boston');
```

The following is my query:

```
select ename, salary
from EMPLOYEES
where Salary >
(select AVG(salary)
from EMPLOYEES);
```

Sql fiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61ca4/1

Answer (score 2):

```
select e.ename,
       e.salary,
       d.DName
  from EMPLOYEES as e
      inner join DEPARTMENTS as d on e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo
where e.Salary > (select AVG(salary) from EMPLOYEES);
```

Sql fiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61ca4/2

Comment: Can I do this without the INNER JOIN?

Comment: @JeffOrris Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

```
select E.ename, E.salary, D.DName

from Employees E, Departments D

where E.Deptno = D.Deptno

And Salary > (select AVG(salary) from EMPLOYEES);
```